# Have my own Listener Richfaces on Cells Table

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, richfaces

I have an XHTML page with two paintings (boards) A and B. In the first table, there are some inputText fields. Changes of their value should be automatically reflected in the other cells and the other table.

My current solution using beans performs badly because the calculations are made at the level of beans. Is there a way to perform it in the presentation level, bypassing the beans as the principle of fomula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could perform your calculations on the clientside (eg. using Javascript) and only update the backing bean once they are complete